# Sporadic chrome aw snap screens

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, knockout.js

We're developing an asp.net mvc 3 application that polls a server on a javascript timer for data. When the data is returned we display it using jquery 1.7.1 and knockout 2.0. The view is a widget displaying some number of notification divs with text and an icon.

When we speed up our timer interval to 5 seconds and return a large amount of notifications a problem occurs. After a random amount of time we get the chrome "Aw Snap" page appearing. Anywhere between 3 minutes to 30 minutes of letting the timer tick. Note that our application needs to opened in the browser 24/7 which is why we went through the long term testing.

After research, it seems there's no way to diagnose an "Aw Snap" page other than looking at google chromes logging. We tried using Sawbuck with verbose logging on which didn't show anything out of the ordinary when the "Aw Snap" page appears.

We are at the point of removing elements from the dom, commenting out code, removing css style, trying everything we can think of to get to the bottom of this. All of which has failed.

Does anyone know what a good next step to take is? What causes chrome Aw Snap pages? Could it be a javascript call or is it likely due to dom manipulation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

When we load up the dump file (mentioned in the comments) in windbg we get this call stack of where the exception occurred. After running the .ecxr command we get: 
    .ecxr command: 0:000> .ecxr
    eax=1a300000 ebx=1ef4fb04 ecx=17323425 edx=3dd5ee49 esi=1ef4faed edi=17323425
    eip=17b12d23 esp=0044eab0 ebp=0044eac0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
    cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
    17b12d23 test    byte ptr [eax+0Ch],4                       ds:002b:1a30000c=??
Call stack: 
    WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
    0x17b12d23
    0x15dcf8ea
    0x2d47cdae
    0x15dcfae5
    0x275a46ca
    0x2d47cdae
    0x2d4a2943
    0x15d0de61
    0x275a3606
    0x275a355d
    0x15d0de61
    0x2d4556b6
    0x15d0de61
    0x15d2345c
    0x1fc6d613
    0x1fc6e5a9
    chrome_1150000!v8::internal::Invoke+0xed [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\v8\src\execution.cc @ 118]
    chrome_1150000!std::_Tree > *,std::less,std::allocator > *> >,0> >::find+0x2f [c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xtree @ 982]
    chrome_1150000!v8::Function::Call+0x12e [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\v8\src\api.cc @ 3604]
    chrome_1150000!WebCore::V8Proxy::instrumentedCallFunction+0x13d [c:\b\build\slave\chrome-official\build\src\third_party\webkit\source\webcore\bindings\v8\v8proxy.cpp @ 432]

Update #2:
Based on ericb's request:

The timer function:

```
$.ajax({
        url: aUpdateUrl,
        type: 'post',
        success: function (aData) {
            try {
                if (self.IsAutoUpdating) {
                    self.OnBeforeDataUpdated();
                    self.Data(aData);
                    self._setUpdateTime();
                    self.DataRefreshed = true;
                    self._applyAutoSizing();
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                self.Widget.HandleError(error);
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            self.Widget.Loaded = true;
            if (self.IsAutoUpdating) {
                self.AutoUpdateTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    self.StartAutoUpdate(self.AutoUpdateUrl);
                }, self.UpdateInterval);
            }
        }
    });
```

Our complete function sets the timer to be called again in self.UpdateInterval time which was set to 5 seconds for our testing.

Additionally, here is the html and how we have it hooked up to knockout:

```
<div id="notifications-@Model.Key" class="notification-items">

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: Dashboard.WidgetLayer@(Model.Key).NotificationModel.notificationsToShow,
    afterRemove: Dashboard.WidgetLayer@(Model.Key).NotificationModel.hideNotificationElement,
    afterAdd: Dashboard.WidgetLayer@(Model.Key).NotificationModel.showNotificationElement }">
    <li class="notification-item group" data-bind="click: Dashboard.WidgetLayer@(Model.Key).NotificationModel.onNotificationClick">
        <div>
            <img class="notification-icon" data-bind="attr: {src: Spec.Icon}" alt="icon"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="notification-content group">
            <div class="notification-header">
                <div class="title">
                    <span class="subject-name" data-bind='text: SubjectTitle'></span>:&nbsp;<span class="spec-title" data-bind='text: Spec.Title'></span>
                </div>
                <button class="acknowledge-notification" data-bind="click: Dashboard.WidgetLayer@(Model.Key).NotificationModel.acknowledgeNotification, clickBubble: false"></button>
                <div class="time-since-event" data-bind='text: FormattedTimestamp'></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <div class="details action-details" data-bind='text: Details'> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

We also have jquery live set up on the notification divs with fade in/fade out as follows:

```
$('#notifications-@Model.Key .notification-item').live({
        mouseenter:
            function() {
                var lElement = this;
                $(lElement).find('.time-since-event').stop(true, true).fadeOut(0, function (){$('.acknowledge-notification', lElement).fadeIn(2000);});

            },
        mouseleave:
            function() {
                var lElement = this;
                $(lElement).find('.acknowledge-notification').stop(true, true).fadeOut(0, function (){$('.time-since-event', lElement).fadeIn(1000);});
            }
    });
```

The rest of the javascript code that updates the notification list is based on knockoutjs's live example of animated transitions available here:
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html

I can provide the code for that if needed but it is 150 lines and decided to exclude it for brevity.

Comment: Something else I should mention. We used perfmon to monitor the chrome and web dev processes while conducting our tests. There was no memory growth before the "Aw Snap" pages.

Comment: We just received an output message in Sawbuck stating a dump file had been created. This message was outputted right after the "Aw Snap" page appeared. Here is a link to the dump file if that might help. http://www.filedropper.com/chrome-last

Comment: could you show some version of the timer code that you've implemented, and/or maybe put that in a jsfiddle and see if it can be replicated?

Comment: I added some code in the post as per your request ericb. Hopefully we are doing something obviously wrong :)

Comment: Try putting all the code into a jsfiddle.net, it helps quite a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/LKS5b/

Comment: We're currently working on the jsfiddle. We have an isolated test written with the same functionality in preparation for the fiddle but haven't been able to reproduce the aw snap crash. We're continuing to work on this and will post when complete.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might want to look at different polling technology. Depending on how many users you have, I would suggest looking at Signalr:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

I recently gave a talk on how to integrate signalr and knockoutjs together.

Slides and examples: http://bit.ly/FamilyFeudSlides

Code: https://github.com/jasonmore/familyfeud

Comment: I'll put that on the last resort pile. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

The cause might be the optimizing engine.

I was experiencing similar problems and I was able to isolated it to an Aw Snap crash caused by the V8 optimizing engine. I had a large function of ~2400 lines which was repeatedly run. After the 300th or so invocation of the function (the number varied quite a bit depending on other seemingly unrelated changes), the optimizing engine would kick in and Windows Task Manager would show a huge spike in the RAM usage which would lead to an "Aw Snap" on the tab.

It turns out that Chrome can be started with the flag --js-flags="--allow-natives-syntax" and then the native V8 javascript command `%NeverOptimizeFunction(functionName);` can be used to prevent Chrome from attempting to run its optimizer.

As can be imagined, this isn't the easiest bug to track down, so I am simply adding this as a suggestion of another thing to consider as a potential cause of the dreaded "Aw Snap".